# C++ STL Producer multiple consumer where producer waits for free consumer before producing next value

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

My little consumer-producer problem had me stumped for some time. I didn't want an implementation where one producer pushes some data round-robin to the consumers, filling up their queues of data respectively.

I wanted to have one producer, x consumers, but the producer waits with producing new data until a consumer is free again. In my example there are 3 consumers so the producer creates a maximum of 3 objects of data at any given time. Since I don't like polling, the consumers were supposed to notify the producer when they are done. Sounds simple, but the solution I found doesn't please me. First the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <map>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_int totalconsumed;

class producer {
    using runningmap_t = std::map<int, std::pair<std::future<void>, bool>>;

    // Secure the map of futures.
    std::mutex mutex_;
    runningmap_t running_;

    // Used for finished notification
    std::mutex waitermutex_;
    std::condition_variable waiter_;

    // The magic number to limit the producer.
    std::atomic<int> count_;

    bool can_run();
    void clean();

    // Fake a source, e.g. filesystem scan.
    int fakeiter;
    int next();
    bool has_next() const;

public:
    producer() : fakeiter(50) {}
    void run();
    void notify(int value);
    void wait();
};

class consumer {
    producer& producer_;
public:
    consumer(producer& producer) : producer_(producer) {}
    void run(int value) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(42));
        std::cout << "Consumed " << value << " on (" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ")" << std::endl;
        totalconsumed++;
        producer_.notify(value);
    }
};


// Only if less than three threads are active, another gets to run.
bool producer::can_run() { return count_.load() < 3; }

// Verify if there's something to consume
bool producer::has_next() const { return 0 != fakeiter; }

// Produce the next value for consumption.
int producer::next() { return --fakeiter; }

// Remove the futures that have reported to be finished.
void producer::clean()
{
    for (auto it = running_.begin(); it != running_.end(); ) {
        if (it->second.second) {
            it = running_.erase(it);
        }
        else { 
            ++it;
        }
    }
}

// Runs the producer. Creates a new consumer for every produced value. Max 3 at a time.
void producer::run()
{
    while (has_next()) {
        if (can_run()) {
            auto c = next();

            count_++;
            auto future = std::async(&consumer::run, consumer(*this), c);

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            running_[c] = std::make_pair(std::move(future), false);

            clean();
        }
        else {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(waitermutex_);
            waiter_.wait(lock);
        }
    }
}

// Consumers diligently tell the producer that they are finished.
void producer::notify(int value)
{
    count_--;

    mutex_.lock();
    running_[value].second = true;
    mutex_.unlock();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> waiterlock(waitermutex_);
    waiter_.notify_all();
}

// Wait for all consumers to finish.
void producer::wait()
{
    while (!running_.empty()) {
        mutex_.lock();
        clean();
        mutex_.unlock();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

// Looks like the application entry point.
int main()
{
    producer p;

    std::thread pthread(&producer::run, &p);
    pthread.join();
    p.wait();

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "Total consumed " << totalconsumed.load() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The part I don't like is the list of values mapped to the futures, called `running_`. I need to keep the `future` around until the `consumer` is actually done. I can't remove the `future` from the map in the `notify` method or else I'll kill the thread that is currently calling `notify`.

Am I missing something that could simplify this construct?

Comment: Do you really want to have it this way?  You could have the producer just fill a lock free queue and the consumers can see if the queue has anything when they are ready and if it does then take it.  IMHO, this is easier to logic about and code.

Comment: I know, but that's less fun ;) It's more or less a thought-experiment. In Java I would probably create a `new Thread` where I now call `std::async` and immediately forget about it, knowing that the JVM will take care of memory. The idea is that a producer creates work but only as much as can be immediately processed. There shall be no queues. Create work, give it to someone, wait until someone's done, create new work.

Comment: *"one producer pushes some data round-robin to the consumers, filling up their queues"* That's not how producer-consumer typically works. Usually, there's one queue, which producer fills and consumers drain at their own pace. A common variation is that the queue size is limited, so producer stops producing once the queue is full. It appears you want this case, with queue size limit equal to the number of consumers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct slotted_data {
  std::size_t I;
  T t;
};
template<class T>
using sink = std::function<void(T)>;
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct async_slots {
  bool produce( slotted_data<T> data ) {
    if (terminate || data.I>=N) return false;
    {
      auto l = lock();
      if (slots[data.I]) return false;
      slots[data.I] = std::move(data.t);
    }
    cv.notify_one();
    return true;
  }
  // rare use of non-lambda cv.wait in the wild!
  bool consume(sink<slotted_data<T>> f) {
    auto l = lock();
    while(!terminate) {
      for (auto& slot:slots) {
        if (slot) {
          auto r = std::move(*slot);
          slot = std::nullopt;
          f({std::size_t(&slot-slots.data()), std::move(r)}); // invoke in lock
          return true;
        }
      }
      cv.wait(l);
    }
    return false;
  }
  // easier and safer version:
  std::optional<slotted_data<T>> consume() {
    std::optional<slotted_data<T>> r;
    bool worked = consume([&](auto&& data) { r = std::move(data); });
    if (!worked) return {};
    return r;
  }
  void finish() {
      {
        auto l = lock();
        terminate = true;
      }
      cv.notify_all();
  }
private:
  auto lock() { return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m); }
  std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::array< std::optional<T>, N > slots;
  bool terminate = false;
};
```

`async_slots` provides a fixed number of slots and an awaitable consume.  If you try to produce two things in the same slot, the producer function returns `false` and ignores you.

`consume` invokes the sink of the data inside the mutex in a continuation passing style.  This permits atomic consumption.

We want to invert producer and consumer:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct slotted_consumer {
  bool consume( std::size_t I, sink<T> sink ) {
    std::optional<T> data;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex m;
    bool worked = slots.produce(
      {
        I,
        [&](auto&& t){
          {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
            data.emplace(std::move(t));
          }
          cv.notify_one();
        }
      }
    );
    if (!worked) return false;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
    cv.wait(l, [&]()->bool{
      return (bool)data;
    });
    sink( std::move(*data) );
    return true;
  }
  bool produce( T t ) {
    return slots.consume(
        [&](auto&& f) {
            f.t( std::move(t) );
        }
    );
  }
  void finish() {
      slots.finish();
  }
private:
  async_slots< sink<T>, N > slots;
};
```

we have to take some care to execute `sink` in a context where we are not holding the mutex of `async_slots`, which is why `consume` above is so strange.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18642489809d481b).

You share a `slotted_consumer< int, 3 > slots`.  The producing thread repeatedly calls `slots.produce(42);`.  It blocks until a new consumer lines up.

Consumer #2 calls `slots.consume( 2, [&](int x){ /* code to consume x */ } )`, and #1 and #0 pass their slot numbers as well.

All 3 consumers can be waiting for the next production.  The above system defaults to feeding #0 first if it is waiting for more work; we could make it "fair" at a cost of keeping a bit more state.

Comment: I've stepped through the code several times and I still haven't fully understood it. It also doesn't help that it doesn't output the correct data (consumer only writes to `cout`). I had to remove the `optional` so it compiles with MSVC2017, could that be it? Can you explain the workflow a bit more?

Comment: @RobertLohr Bug in slotted consumer consume fixed (I needed to wait for the produce callback to run).  `finish()` method added to make cleanup simpler, and all functions now return `bool` to indicate that they failed (possibly due to `finish()` being called).  Live example added.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I just simply didn't find any time to look at this sooner. Now that I have a working example I get it. One note: on MSVC `async_slots::terminate` must be initialized to `false` or everything will stop immediately. Thank you.

Comment: One small flaw: when removing the calls to sleep and have it run at full speed, the consumers might not come to an end because the producer is shut down while consumers are still waiting. They have to be notified explicitly in `finish()` for example.

Comment: @robert oops, always inline init everything.  My bad.